# Rebind Enter to right arrow in Visual Studio autocompletion

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When navigating in the autompletion list I use arrows, so in my opinion it would be simpler to select items with the <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> instead of the default  <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Is there a way (maybe plugin) in Visual Studio to rebind <kbd>Enter</kbd> to <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> when in autompletion mode?

I would like to use this feature in a C++ project.

Comment: You make it sound like pressing Right Arrow is "simpler" than pressing Enter, but I'm struggling to see how that's the case. Presumably all you're really trying to do is preserve a habit.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Software abides by the user's rules, not the other way around. Especially not MSVS :p

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit When navigating in autompletion list I use arrows, so in my opinion it would be simpler to select with the right arrow instead of "reaching out" for Enter

Comment: Depends on the version of Visual Studio. Not sure but it sounds like you want to look at the _Edit.CompleteWord_ binding.

Comment: @captain-obvlious  Edit.CompleteWord just shows the completion's list

Comment: @Bretsko: Could you add that into the question? It really gives some much-needed context to your request.